# Partial sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, coding-theory

For a given $n$, find the minimal $r$ such that.

$$2^r\sum_{i=0}^r {n \choose i} \ge 2^n$$

What can we say about $\frac{r}{n}$ as $n \to \infty$?

I wrote a small script and it looks like there's a limit (around 0.22709), although the expression is not monotonically decreasing, here's the
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YualE.png).

I wonder if there's anything analytical to say about this question, to prove if a limit exists, or to bound this value.

For context, this question came up when I was looking for particular coverings of $\Bbb Z_2^n$ with hamming spheres, specifically $2^r$ spheres with radius r.

Comment: Seems to me that $r=\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: Estimating sums of the form $\sum_{i=0}^{\rho n}\binom n i$ is often seen in information theory, and leads to the binary  entropy function. I don't remember the details (see Qiaochu's +1 post for them), but I would think it is in most books on information theory/coding theory. I do find that part of those books boring because I'm an algebra guy at heart. So in that sense I understand :-)

Answer (score 9):

I'll be a little sloppy below; the goal will only be to figure out the constant. This argument could be made rigorous with more careful attention to bounds. Below $\approx$ means that two expressions are within a polynomial-of-$n$ factor of each other.

Write $a_r = \sum_{i=0}^r {n \choose i}$. We have the crude bounds ${n \choose r} \le a_r \le r  {n \choose r}$, so $a_r \approx {n \choose r}$. Writing $r = pn$, [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) then gives

$$\begin{align*} {n \choose pn} &\approx \frac{ \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n}{ \left( \frac{pn}{e} \right)^{pn} \left( \frac{(1-p)n}{e} \right)^{(1-p)n} } \\
 &= \frac{n^n}{(pn)^{pn} ((1-p)n)^{(1-p)n} } \\
 &= \frac{1}{p^{pn} (1-p)^{(1-p)n}} \\
 &= 2^{n H_2(p)} \end{align*}$$

where $H_2(p) = - p \log_2 p - (1 - p) \log_2 (1 - p)$ is the [binary entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function); this is the *entropy approximation* to the binomial coefficients. So we want to find $p$ such that

$$2^r {n \choose r} \approx 2^{n(p + H_2(p))} \approx 2^n$$

which means the value of $p$ we want is the smallest positive real solution to

$$\boxed{p + H_2(p) = 1}.$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x+-+x+log_2+x+-+%281+-+x%29+log_2+%281+-+x%29+from+x+%3D+0+to+0.5) can plot this function but for whatever reason can't solve this equation even numerically.

[image]

In any case the plot clearly shows a solution around $p = 0.22 \dots $ as you've found, and since the function is so well-behaved [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) can compute $p$ quickly to high accuracy. Here the Newton's method iteration is

$$p_{n+1} = p_n - \frac{p_n + H(p_n) - 1}{1 - \log_2 \frac{p_n}{1-p_n}}$$

and we can take, say, $p_0 = 0.2$ as our initial guess. After three iterations we get $\boxed{ p_3 = 0.2270921952 \dots }$ and these digits are stable after further iteration (at least up to the accuracy Google Sheets uses by default).

Generally, understanding the asymptotics of $a_r$ amounts to understanding the probability that a binomial distribution is far from its mean. This is the subject of [large deviations inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory), and in particular [Cramer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem_(large_deviations)) can be applied here to produce a bound that will be a more rigorous version of the above.